# How to specify multiple C++ tests in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, gradle-native

I am trying to migrate a project from Maven+CMake to Gradle. For the most part is good, but I could not find a way to specify the test executions that I would specify with CTest.

Is there some example/resource that I could use to get started?

I tried to look in the tutorials and documentation of Gradle. I also tried to search for CMake/Ctest to Gradle migration tutorials. But I could not find relevant information.

In a nutshell, I need to specify different executions. Some starting with the test binary, some starting with Java.